# How to iterate over files in a folder and encode them to base64 to store in an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, iteration

```
Dir.foreach("/home/kaustubh/Downloads/resumes") do |fopen|
...d << Base64.encode64(file.read)
end
```

I am reading files in a ruby terminal and trying to encode entire files to base64 format, but my the output comes as an array with all values empty.

The array d should store all the files in the array in their base64 encoded format.

Comment: As a follow up question, I am trying to HTTP post the base64 encoded file in a URL. But it shows an error 414, uri too long. Is there a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the directory of interest is held by the variable `target_dir`. Then we would want:

```
require 'base64'

files_of_interest(target_dir).map { |f| Base64.encode64(File.read(file)) }
```

where it remains to write the method `files_of_interest`.

Here are some data (Linux).

```
ls -la testdir
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary  32 Jul 27 09:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary 346 Jul 27 09:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cary cary   0 Jul 27 09:22 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 cary cary   0 Jul 27 09:22 file2
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary  28 Jul 27 11:41 subdir

ls -la testdir/subdir
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary 28 Jul 27 11:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary 32 Jul 27 09:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cary cary  0 Jul 27 09:23 file3
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary 10 Jul 27 11:41 subsubdir

ls -la testdir/subdir/subsubdir
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary 10 Jul 27 11:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 cary cary 28 Jul 27 11:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cary cary  0 Jul 27 11:41 file4
```

**Case 1: construct an array of all the files in `testdir` that are not directories**

One could use [Dir::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D), [Dir::glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) or [Dir::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Dir.html#method-c-foreach).

*Using `[]`*

```
def files_of_interest(target_dir)
  Dir["#{target_dir}/*"].select { |f| File.file?(f) }
end

files_of_interest("testdir")
  #=> ["testdir/file1", "testdir/file2"]
```

Note

```
Dir["#{target_dir}/*"]
  #=> ["testdir/file1", "testdir/file2", "testdir/subdir"]
```

*Using `glob`*

```
def files_of_interest(target_dir)
  Dir.glob("#{target_dir}/*").select { |f| File.file?(f) }
end

files_of_interest("testdir")
  #=> ["testdir/file1", "testdir/file2"]
```

*Using `foreach`*

```
def files_of_interest(target_dir)
  Dir.foreach(target_dir).map { |f| "#{target_dir}/#{f}" }.
      select { |f| File.file?(f) }
  end

files_of_interest("testdir")
  #=> ["testdir/file1", "testdir/file2"]
```

Note

```
enum = Dir.foreach(target_dir)
  #=> #<Enumerator: Dir:foreach("testdir")> 
enum.to_a
  #=> [".", "..", "file1", "file2", "subdir"]
```

See [File::file?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#method-c-file-3F). Note we could replace `Array#select` with `Array#reject` and `File::file?` with [File::directory?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#method-c-directory-3F).

**Case 2: construct an array of all the files in `testdir` and its nested subdirectories  that are not directories**

Here we must use `Dir::glob`.

```
def files_of_interest(target_dir)
  Dir.glob("#{target_dir}/**/*").select { |f| File.file?(f) }
end

files_of_interest("testdir")
  #=> ["testdir/file1", "testdir/file2", "testdir/subdir/file3",
  #    "testdir/subdir/subsubdir/file4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Ruby code doesn't do anything. If you copy and paste that into IRB you get errors.

From what you've written, you want to read every file in a directory and encode it as base64 and then store the base64 in an array. Here's how you'd do that:

```
d = []
Dir['/home/kaustubh/Downloads/resumes/*'].each do |file|
  d << Base64.encode64(File.read(file))
end
```

`Dir['/home/kaustubh/Downloads/resumes/*']` will return an array of paths for the contents of that directory. (including subdirectories, so be careful)

Then you call `.each do |file|` on that array, and for each `file` in the array you call `File.read` to read the file into a string object. Then you encode the string with `Base64.encode64` and store it in your array.

Comment: You say, "including subdirectories, so be careful", but disregard your own advice in your code by attempting to `File.read(f)` where `f` is a directory (e.g., '.' or '..'), which of course raises an exception!

Comment: ...except my code doesn’t return . and .. (which aren’t subdirectories, which is what I warned about) and the example given appeared to indicate no subdirectories. If OP would like to clarify their example they can, but since they accepted this answer I presume it worked for them, and should it stop working they’ll know why.

Comment: Yes, your code does not return `'.'`, or `'.'` (my mistake). With the directory structure in my answer `1Dir['testdir/*'] #=> ["testdir/file1", "testdir/file2", "testdir/subdir"]` where the last is a directory. No reflection on the asker, but you should know better that the choice of answer by a Ruby newbie means, er, not so much. :-)

Comment: Are we second guessing the asker now? They had a narrow use-case and this answer worked for them. [Accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) doesn't mean it's the best answer encompassing all edge-cases for all future visitors, "it simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally." OP is absolutely welcome to un-accept it and accept another answer if they want. Not sure that'll happen since this answer appears to have worked for them personally.

Comment: I am not second-guessing the asker. The question is mute about whether `/home/kaustubh/Downloads/resumes` contains subdirectories. That being the case, we must assume that it may, as both @Mig and I did. Alternatively, you should state your assumption that it contains no subdirectories.

Comment: I did. Again, it's safe to assume it didn't since the answer worked for the asker.

Comment: I accepted the answer because my use case was one where there were no subdirectories. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not complete so I am not sure this is what you're after but this does collect each file's content in Base64:

```
require 'base64'

files_glob = "/home/kaustubh/Downloads/resumes/*"

base64_array = Dir.glob(files_glob).select do |filename|
  File.file? filename
end.map do |filename|
  Base64.encode64(File.read(filename))
end
```

If your files are all finishing with an extension, you could avoid the `select` block and `glob` with `"/home/kaustubh/Downloads/resumes/*.txt"` instead for example.

The select block is just for excluding directories. As opposed to `foreach`, `glob` does not seem to include "." and ".." directories. But you may have other ones. Always better to be more specific.

Using `glob` instead of `foreach` allows you to use any iterator methods like `select` and more importantly `map` instead of just iterating.